# Can my school see the websites I've visited while on my home WiFi after I reconnect to the schools?

Tags: privacy, wifi, google, websites, monitoring

I know that they can't monitor me on my home WiFi, but can they see the websites I visited while on my home WiFi after I reconnect to the schools?

Comment: Does the computer belong to you or to the school?

Comment: I would assume, not knowing any more about your setup: yes, they can. Until you prove they can't, assume the worst. Also, depending on whether you use school accounts like Google accounts, the likelihood increases.

Comment: @Pheric no, not if it is a personal device without the school's agent installed

Comment: @schroeder Unless it's a school account that they are logged into while searching Google for things, in which case their searches will be saved. It's not specifically what they're asking for but might be something they need to know

Comment: @Pheric then that has nothing to do with what wifi network you're connected to ... It's an account thing that's searchable no matter where you are. My point is you can't make blanket statements. There can be a definitive and knowable answer.

Comment: @schroeder Fair enough, but OP might not understand what they're asking. But I get your point. Feel free to delete my comments if you think that would clean up the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Probably not**. However, if you set your browser to reopen all tabs when you start it, then they might see what your last open tabs were.